# How to give a user a specific set of variables to choose from?

Tags: c#, class

```
           Console.WriteLine("The story begins with. . . Oh yes, what is your name?");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Awesome! " + name + " it is then");
        Console.WriteLine("This story takes place in 2077. A few years after nuclear annihilation \n " +           "comes to the human race. Now we have to get you prepared for your survival \n" +
        "in this new wasteland until your doom is inevitably upon you. \n" +
        "By the way what was your profession " + name + " before the wasteland?");
```

So my plan was to give the user a set of variables, for example, police officer, firefighter, survivalist, etc. These variables will already have preset attribute points assigned to each variable which I can create. I would just like to know how to go about giving them the selection. In the midst of creating this, I figured I might actually have to use classes. I'm still confused about how to bring it as a choice selection though. They will type in the name once they decide which will be picked up by a Console.ReadLine();

Comment: You could present the user a numbered list and ask them to input a number. You could then use that number as an index to retrieve an item from the list.

Comment: Thanks! Never even thought of that. I remember working with classes but couldn't remember much so a review is in order. I'll definitely give this a try though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this.  Here is one simple example. Enums can be a useful choice here because they have a name and numeric value and can be treated as Int32 types because that is their value under the hood.

```
void Main()
{
    var choice = ProfessionChoice();
    
}


public int ProfessionChoice()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please pick from the list:\n\n");
    
    foreach(var profession in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Profession)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{(int)profession} - {profession}");
    }
    Console.Write("\n\nEnter Choice > ");
    var result = Console.ReadLine();
    
    var choice = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(result, out choice);
    
    Console.WriteLine($"\n\nYou picked {(Profession)choice}");
    
    return choice;
    
}


public enum Profession
{
    PoliceOfficer = 1,
    FireFighter = 2,
    Survivalist = 3
}
```